# How to use boost::serialization for std::stack?

Tags: c++, boost, stack, std, boost-serialization

I know we can use boost::serialization for std::vector , list ,map etc as long as I include the corresponding boost header file like:

```
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
```

But how could I use boost::serialization for std::stack ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I recently came across this problem.  I was not satisfied with the solution of using std::deque because I really needed *only* a stack interface.  Currently, boost support serialization of std::stack this by including these header files *in this order*

```
#include "boost/serialization/deque.hpp"
#include "boost/serialization/stack.hpp"
```

A complete example would look something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include "boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp"
#include "boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp"
#include "boost/serialization/deque.hpp"
#include "boost/serialization/stack.hpp"

struct s
{
    std::stack<std::string> stack;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & stack;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `std::stack` with `std::deque` and include:

```
#include <boost/serialization/deque.hpp>
```